# How do I print the sum of all of my numbers on CodeHS 8.4.5: Five Numbers?

Tags: python

Using a for loop, ask the user for five numbers. Store those numbers in a list. Each time you add a new number to your list, print the list. (Your list will initially be empty.)

You should report the sum of the numbers in the list at the end.

An example run of your program might look like this:

```
Number: 3
[3]
Number: 6
[3, 6]
Number: 12
[3, 6, 12]
Number: 2
[3, 6, 12, 2]
Number: -5
[3, 6, 12, 2, -5]
Sum: 18
```

This is my code right now:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(5):
    new_number = int(input("Number: "))
    my_list.append(new_number)
    print my_list
print "Sum: " + new_number*5
```

I almost have this code right. There's just one problem: I need to print the sum. Right now, it's an error because I have a `str` and `int` object on line 6 and I need that fixed.

This is the error that it gives:

```
Error: Line 6
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects on line 6
```

Comment: to have the sum printed at your last line replace your last line with `print "Sum: " + str(sum(my_list))`

Comment: Your code only works with positive numbers. It has to work with negative numbers too.

Comment: are you sure it's the sign of the numbers that causes the problem ? can you add the given error, or the trace call please

Comment: I just added the error that it gives.

Comment: there is no int in my code, check the code in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = []
for i in range(5):
    new_number = int(input("Number: "))
    my_list.append(new_number)
    print my_list
print("Sum: " + str(sum(my_list)))
```

I replaced your last line in the code with the one in my previous comment, seems to be working fine, in both cases positive and negative numbers

here is another way to do it,

```
sum = 0
for i in range(5):
    sum += int(input("Number: "))
print("Sum: " + str(sum))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = []
for i in range(5):
    new_number = int(input("Number: "))
    my_list.append(new_number)
    print (my_list)
b= sum(my_list)
c=str(b)
print ("Sum: " + c)
```

Your code missed:
brackets in line 5 for printing
getting the sum for the list
converting sum to string for final concatenation before printing in last line

Answer (score 0):

It is just this.

```
num = 0
for i in range(5):
    new_number = int(input("Number: "))
    num+=new_number
    print num
```

Not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = []
for i in range(5):
    new_number = int(input("Number: "))
    my_list.append(new_number)
    print(my_list)
sum=my_list[0]+my_list[1]+my_list[2]+my_list[3]+my_list[4]
print ("Sum: " + str(sum))
```

Comment: This answer is okay but an easier and more scalable way to get the sum would be to do `sum(my_list)`